# I want to write a app by using openstreetmap. How can I get the position by searching a place's name?

Tags: java, android, openstreetmap

I'm using osm for android and I don't know how can I get the position by the name of a place.

Answer (score 1):

Getting a position by name is called geocoding. You will need to ask a geocoder, such as [Nominatim](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim) or one of the other [OSM-based search engines](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Search_engines).